# Узнать в сборке имя namespace и имя класса функции Main

Tags: c#

Узнать в сборке имя namespace и имя класса функции Main

```
    Assembly asm = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.GetFullPath(dllName));
Type t = asm.GetType("Здесь namespace сборки + точка + имя класса функции Main", true, true);
// Create class Program
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
var method = t.GetMethod("StartMethod");
CW = method.Invoke(obj, null) as List<string>;
```

Comment: В этом вопросе не хватает вопроса. Этот код не работает? Как вы это поняли?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Assembly asm = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(Path.GetFullPath(dllName));
Type typeWithMain = asm.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic) != null)
    .SingleOrDefault();
if (typeWithMain != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]